# how Assert.Equal does casting to compare?

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm a little bit confused how  Assert.Equal() works, below is some simple code:

```
//Assert.Equal(XXX expected, XXX actual); expected is always the first parameter and actual is the second parameter
```

```
 Assert.Equal("a string", 2019);
```

the compiler error says cannot convert 'int' to `IEnumerable<char>`, which indicated that Assert.Equal will cast "actual" argument(second argument)  to the type of "expected" argument (first argument) and then compare

But if I swap the argument around as:

```
Assert.Equal(2019, "string");
```

the error still says cannot convert 'int' to `IEnumerable<char>`, which means Assert.Equal cast "expected" argument to the type of "actual" argument, so how come Assert.Equal sometimes casts "actual" type to "expected" type and sometimes casts "expected" type to "actual" type, how this inconsistency occurs?

Comment: As you're getting a *compiler* error, it can't be affected by the *implementation* of `Assert.Equal`. It's just a matter of what the declared parameter types are. There are various overloads available - the compiler is trying to find the closest match, then reporting the error against that.

Comment: @JonSkeet   but all overloads has first parameter as "expected" and second parameter as "actual", so there can only be one way to do casting?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is `Assert.Equal` no 's' in the end

Comment: If you want to learn how a method is implemented, I'd recommend looking at the decompiled assembly. Just install ILSpy or DotPeek, open the dll and see for yourself. In this case @JonSkeet is right, and the compiler just can't find which method overload to use.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess you are talking about the UnitTesting dll, secondimage is using xUnit

Comment: @iosiG  but all overloads has first parameter as "expected" and second parameter as "actual", so there is only one way casting. if the code cast expected to actual first, how come later it cast actual to expected. the other way around?

Comment: @TimSchmelter so it is correct to say that all overload Equal cast "actual" type to "expected" type?

Comment: `actual` and `expected` are the argument names, not their types.  So for any overload version of the method the types of both arguments are same. So you can not not have one argument passed as integer and another as string. They both either need to be string or integer.

Comment: Again, this isn't casting. This isn't a matter of implementation. You could see exactly the same behavior by writing your own no-op methods. The compiler is unable to find an applicable overload for your arguments, and it's trying to convey that in the best way it can.

Comment: Why the error is the same if you swap the arguments relies on the implementation of the compiler code and not on how `Equal` was implemented. Maybe he always mentions the value type before the reference type. But these are really implementation details. The compiler just tells you that there is no method to call with your arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no casting involved at all!

`Assert.Equal` has a lot of overloads, but all of them compare values of the same type, so you cannot compare 2 values of different types in the first place.

By the complicated rules of overload resolution, the compiler resolves both of your calls to this overload:

```
public static void Equal<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual)
```

In both cases, it infers that `T` is `char`, and tries to convert your `int` argument to `IEnumerable<char>`.

There is no inconsistency here. The compiler simply finds the most specific overload, and tries to convert all your arguments to the types required by that overload. It succeeded with converting the string to `IEnumerable<char>`, but failed with the `int`. If you try to call `Equal` with `int` and some other type:

```
Assert.Equal(1, Guid.NewGuid());
```

You'll see a different error like `the type arguments cannot be inferred from usage...`.

This essentially shows that the compiler is not trying to convert the first argument to the type of the second, nor trying to convert the second argument to the type of the first. It's just trying to convert both arguments to the type that the method expects.

If you really want to call `Equal` with two different types, you could specify a type parameter of `object`,

```
Assert.Equal<object>(2019, "2019");
```

hence forcing the compiler to choose this overload:

```
public static void Equal<T>(T expected, T actual)
```